# (ssg-wsg) Why is CorpPass ID required for Update/Delete course run with sessions API?

Tags: ssg

Does anyone know why is CorpPass Id a required field for "Update/Delete course run with sessions" API? Since this will be an NRIC, would it be a sensitive information to be used in the request body?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the API: https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/docs/product/6kYpfJEWVb7NyYVVHvUmHi/group/374zmR5D0tQeS87eA1hrLV/api/4i96CWAYWH6uGhkhGMZxHd/version/3egIPKn3WK27liSToemjDV

Based on the API page, I do not see where Corppass ID is being referenced. Do provide more details if you have a technical query for the API.

However, based on the description: API is only available to Corppass users - and if you are able to subscribe to it then you are a Corporate Developer. For this query, it would be more appropriate if you can reach out to their servicedesk for details instead: https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/faq?anchor=WhoCanIContactIfIHaveQuestionsAboutTheseAPIs